# Mongoose find() with multipe values

Tags: node.js, api, mongoose

I am trying to find() multi ids from product collection by using thisCart array which has aswell a few ids which I want to compare. 
I tried a few ways to do so with no success.

```
cart.findOne({"user_id": userId, "activeCart": true}).then(thisCart => {
        Product.find({"product_id": prodId})
        // here thisCart bring back arrays with multi ids 
       // which I want to do foreach thisCart[i].id = Product.product_id
       // and eventually get all the products which equal to thisCart[i].id
        res.status(200).json({

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

First, because you using `chart.findOne(...)`, will return only one data.

Try with `async await` and `array.map` like this :

```
app.get('/your end point', async (req,res) => {
try{
 const thiChart = await Cart.findOne({"user_id": userId, "activeCart": true});
 const thisProduct = await  Product.find({"product_id": prodId});
 const result = thisProduct.map(item => {
  return item.id = thisChart.id //or may be anything you want
 }) //using array.map will return array

 console.log(result) //optional 

 res.status(200).json({
  result
 });

} catch (error){
  console.log(error)
  }
 }
)
```

I hope this can may help you

Comment: Actually I am using the following:
NodeJs
Mongoose
TypeScript
Cart is the model schema I am using
```
const shoppingCartSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user_id: { type: String, required: true},
    cart_date: { type: String, required: true},
    activeCart: { type: Boolean, required: true },
    cart_content: [{
        product_id: { type: String, required: true},
        product_quantity: { type: Number, required: true},
    }]
})
```